# Pi Performance: tcpdump vs wireshark

Tags: networking, debian

Questions:

1. Which tool you would use to <del>network</del> capture a network bridge and why? focused on performance? heat built-up? focused on configuration options?
2. Is it possible to capture special ports like ONLY port 80/9100 (more or less) with one of these tools? what would be the best mode to do that? are there options to parse analysed data for keywords/domains/whatever or is this a scenario i have to do after capturing?
3. Is it possible to save each data STREAM directly to a single file? e.g. stream of a captured printer job on 9100? (are there any other sites of SO discussing that kind of questions?)

kindly

Comment: "... to <del>network</del> **capture** a network bridge ..." I guess? What has nmap to do with this, do you mean `tcpdump`?

Comment: ..what a bloomer ;) you are completly right ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `tcpdump` because it is small (self + dependencies). You can specify a *capture* filter that restricts the capture, for example (assuming interface `eth0`):

```
tcpdump -w capture.pcap -i eth0 'tcp port 80 or tcp port 9100'
```

If you have wireshark installed, then an alternative command that produces a capture file in a newer format:

```
dumpcap -w capture.pcapng -i eth0 -f 'tcp port 80 or tcp port 9100'
```

A *display* filter can be used to limit the output of the data (replace `wireshark` by `tshark` for textual output instead of a GUI):

```
wireshark -r capture.pcap -Y 'http.host == example.com'
```

For real-time capture you can also combine these options (the filter option can also be specified in the UI so you could omit it from the command if you'd like to):

```
wireshark -w capture.pcapng -i eth0 -f 'tcp port 80 or tcp port 9100' -Y 'http.host == example.com'
```

Then to save a TCP stream, right-click on a packet and pick "Follow TCP stream". In the new window, you have the option to save the captured data.

Comment: is it possible to do the last step "to save a TCP Stream" automatically? like: save all streams you recieved completly? and just for my understanding: a display filter is equivalent to grep on the output/stdout?

Comment: @AlexTape A display filter can act on any property of the packet, it does much more than simply searching for a string. `tshark` has a `-z follow,tcp,...` option (see manpage) if you want to automate it, but last time I tried it, it was [buggy](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9541). Anyway, to extract a certain field, you can try `tshark -T fields -e tcp.segment_data -r some.pcapng`.  (look for other fields in the manual or `tshark -G fields | grep something | column -t -s $'\t'`)

Answer (score 0):

Both are useful tools and require installation of [winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) / [libpcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libpcap/),  but Wireshark will be my choice.It has the most powerful display filters can do live capture and offline analysis.  See more info from here their [site](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Some other easy-to-use network traffic monitoring and analyzing tools. You can go for a try.

[Colasoft Capsa Free](http://www.colasoft.com/) - Network Analyzer

[Angry IP Scanner](http://angryip.org/w/Download) - Network Scanner

Comment: i know wireshark/tcpdump and their technique. the question is about what would be the best decision on rPi and how to directly filter/save the incoming network stream properly.